# dynamically add new item in combo box without using data store

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I have multiple combo boxes on my page and each one of them are holding different values so i don't want to create a separate data store for each of them , rather i want a way to dynamically add new values to those combo boxes without using data store.

```
 var comboOne = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
            value: val,
            name:'L_PHONE',
                store: [val],
                displayField:'value',
                typeAhead: true,
                mode: 'local',
                forceSelection: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                width:100,

                selectOnFocus:true,
                applyTo: id
            });
```

so i just need a way to add new values dynamically like **comboOne.setValue('NEW')** but this function only add value at the top and overrides the newly added value

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your question, there are two things associated with ExtJS combobox.
1. The **options** that you see in the dropdown when you click on the trigger
2. The **value** that the combo is holding at any given point of time. If you submit the form, this is the value that is going to be submitted. You can modify the value by *selecting* an option in #1 (by this, I don't mean that selecting is not the only way to set the value)

Your question is related to #1 above but what you are trying to do is modifying the value in #2

Now that it is clear why what you are doing is not working the way you expect it to, here is the answer to your question -

The option list in Combobox in ExtJS is always backed by a store. To be able to add an option in the options list that appears as a dropdown, you will have to add the option (record) to the store backing the particular combobox.

This is as simple as -

```
comboOne.getStore().add(comboOne.getStore().recordType({value:'NEWVAL'});
```

Comment: Well i am getting record undefined error and at the same time do i need to crate separate data store for every combobox as if i use the common data store then change in one data store would reflect all comboboxes so i don't want to use datastore instead i need a direct method to insert a new item

Comment: how are you using a common datastore? in that case, just add the record to the common datastore and it will reflect everywhere.

Comment: Well thats the issue i don't want to reflect changes everywhere , as i have mentioned in the question that i have mulitple combo boxes and each box is holding different values. so i want to update them independently.

Comment: Well, you cannot have the same store used by multiple comboboxes yet expect different options in these comboboxes. if you want the options to be different you need each combo backed by a separate store. i am not sure why you *dont* want store per combo but if it is performance reasons, it can be tackled.